# SwiftUI aspectFill

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

What is `SwiftUI` equivalent of `UIImageView` `aspectFill` option?

When I do

```
Image(self.chat.thumbnailName)
.resizable()
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
.clipped()
```

(also tried to add `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` or `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)`

I still get an ugly distorted image:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `.scaledToFill` or `.scaledToFit` modifiers, per needs. So in your case

```
Image(self.chat.thumbnailName)
.resizable()
.scaledToFill()
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
.clipped()
```

Comment: Make sure .resizable() is the first property, otherwise it won't work.